# How do I delete the drop-down arrow of the drop-down menu while keeping the border-image of QSS？

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I changed a QPushButton into a drop-down menu. My codes are as follows:

```
m_menu = new QMenu(this);
        m_addAction = new QAction(m_menu);
        m_delAction = new QAction(m_menu);
        m_addAction->setText(QObject::tr("add"));
        m_delAction->setText(QObject::tr("del"));
        m_menu->addAction(m_addAction);
        m_menu->addAction(m_delAction);
 m_menu->setStyleSheet("\
                       QMenu {\
                       background-image: url(:/img/tanchu-1.png);; /*background-image*/\
                       border: 3px solid rgb(235,110,36);/*menu border*/\
                       }\
                       QMenu::item {\
                       font-size: 10pt; \
                       color: rgb(225,225,225);\
                       border: 3px solid rgb(60,60,60);\
                       background-image: url(:/img/tanchu-1.png);\
                       padding:160px 160px;\
                       margin:2px 2px;\
                       }\
                       QMenu::item:selected { \
                       background-color:rgb(235,110,36);\
                       }\
                       QMenu::item:pressed {\
                       border: 1px solid rgb(60,60,61); \
                       background-color: rgb(220,80,6); \
                       }\
                       ");
ui->pushButton->setMenu(m_menu);
```

and the button I get looks like this[image: image1]. There is a black drop-down arrow in the lower right corner.

But now the problem  is that when I remove the drop-down arrow from the drop-down menu by using

```
ui->pushButton->setStyleSheet("QPushButton::menu-indicator{image:none;}");
```

the border-image that I set to the QPushButton with QSS `border-image: url(:/img/btn_mid_0.png);`disappears like image2 [image: image 2]. The drop-down arrow and the border-image disapper together. How do I remove the drop-down arrow while maintaining the border-image I set before?
Besides, the The width of the submenu does not change with the qpushbutton like image3[image: image3]. How can I set the width of the drop-down menu to be as wide as the QPushButton?
Thanks!

All my codes are as follows:
mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QMenu *m_menu;
    QAction *m_addAction;
    QAction *m_delAction;
    QPushButton *m_pushButton;

    void addFunc();
    void delFunc();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMenu>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    m_menu = new QMenu(this);
        m_addAction = new QAction(m_menu);
        m_delAction = new QAction(m_menu);
        m_addAction->setText(QObject::tr("add"));
        m_delAction->setText(QObject::tr("del"));
        m_menu->addAction(m_addAction);
        m_menu->addAction(m_delAction);
        connect(m_addAction, &QAction::triggered, this, &MainWindow::addFunc);
        connect(m_delAction, &QAction::triggered, this, &MainWindow::delFunc);

 m_menu->setStyleSheet("\
                       QMenu {\
                       background-image: url(:/img/tanchu-1.png);; /*background-image*/\
                       border: 3px solid rgb(235,110,36);/*menu border*/\
                       }\
                       QMenu::item {\
                       font-size: 10pt; \
                       color: rgb(225,225,225);\
                       border: 3px solid rgb(60,60,60);\
                       background-image: url(:/img/tanchu-1.png);\
                       padding:160px 160px;\
                       margin:2px 2px;\
                       }\
                       QMenu::item:selected { \
                       background-color:rgb(235,110,36);\
                       }\
                       QMenu::item:pressed {\
                       border: 1px solid rgb(60,60,61); \
                       background-color: rgb(220,80,6); \
                       }\
                       ");
  ui->pushButton->setMenu(m_menu);

  ui->pushButton->setStyleSheet("QPushButton::menu-indicator{image:none;}");

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::addFunc()
{
    qDebug() << "addFunc";
}

void MainWindow::delFunc()
{
    qDebug() << "delFunc";
}
```

Comment: Please provide a full example, including any images. For instance, we can't see where you're setting a border-image on the button.  Though by setting the button CSS like you show here, you're overwriting any CSS you may have set on it earlier. You'd need to get the existing CSS, then `.append()` to it, then set the result on the  button.

Comment: "how can I set the width of the drop-down menu to be as wide as the QPushButton?" Is kinda a separate question, but let me ask, is the button set to a fixed width, or is it going to vary with the available layout size? (hint: it would be much simpler with a fixed width :)

Comment: Sorry for I haven't provide enough message about my question. I have add images and all codes into my question. The border-image QSS of QPushButton is set in the UI designer, others by codes in mainwindow.cpp.

Comment: I want the width of the submenus to always be the same as the width of the QPushButton. Unlike in figure 3, where the button is longer, the submenu is still the same length as before.

Comment: I want the width of the submenus to always be the same as the width of the QPushButton. Unlike in figure 3, where the button is longer, the submenu is still the same length as before.

Answer (score 4):

Just set *all* the button CSS in one place, either in the QtCreator/Designer properties, *or* in the C++ code, not both. Basically your C++ CSS is overriding what you set in designer view.

In Designer view just use something like this for the `styleSheet` property:

```css
QPushButton { border-image: url(:/img/btn_mid_0.png); }
QPushButton::menu-indicator { image: none; }
```

Or the same thing in C++ but with quotes :)

As for the menu styling... I'm not sure what's going on in there now (looks strange!) but the simplest way to have their sizes match is to set the size for both explicitly, either in CSS (`width: XXXpx;`) or in C++ (`QWidget::setFixedWidth(XXX)`). The C++ version may work better if the button is managed by a layout, since what happens with CSS size properties then gets vague. For CSS sometimes `min-width` and/or `max-width` work better than just `width`.

Comment: The problem has been solved! Thank you very much! This problem has been bothering me for three days. Thank you!